# Convertir canvas base 64 a un archivo

Tags: php, javascript, canvas

Tengo este `JavaScript`:

```
//imgConverted es una img en html
//myCanvas es una gráfica en canvas 
//btnDisplay es un botón con la función que convierte canvas en base64
//imagen es el input file donde quiero colocar la imagen para posteriormente con una función envíe esta imagen a un archivo `PHP` y este haga la acción de enviar al servidor

const imgConverted = document.querySelector('#imgConverted');
const myCanvas = document.querySelector("#densityChart");
const btnDisplay = document.querySelector("#btnDisplay");
const imagen = document.querySelector("#imagen");

btnDisplay.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const dataURI = myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    imgConverted.src = dataURI;
    //console.log(dataURI);     
});
```

Al oprimir `btnDisplay` este hace el canvas en `base64` lo que quiero es pasar el `dataURI` a `blob` y posteriormente este a un file para poder insertar la imagen en una carpeta en mi servidor. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: dependerá del lenguaje de servidor que utilices.

Comment: php en el servidor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El proceso es prácticamente el mismo que el que te respondí en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298814/guardar-canvas-autom%c3%a1ticamente-en-carpeta-del-servidor/298835#298835) usando `Chart.js`:

**JavaScript:**

```
const btnDisplay = document.querySelector("#btnDisplay");
const myCanvas = document.querySelector("#densityChart");

btnDisplay.addEventListener("click", () => {
    saveImage( myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
});

const saveImage = (base64) => {
    var data = base64.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,(.+)$/, "$1");
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "/saveImageOnServer.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(`imageData=${data}`);
};
```

**PHP (saveImageOnServer.php):**

```
$data = $_POST['imageData'];
file_put_contents('/my_server_folder/image.png', base64_decode($data));
```

**Edición:** Si te interesara descargar la imagen sin tener que enviarla al servidor, puedes usar el [parámetro download de HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/a#Atributos) en un elemento `a` para lograrlo. [Aquí puedes encontrar cómo hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51857/guardar-una-captura-del-canvas/51871#51871).

Answer (score 1):

La función `atob()` decodifica una cadena de datos que ha sido codificada usando la codificación en base 64.

Por el contrario, la función `btoa()` crea una cadena ASCII codificada en base 64 a partir de una "cadena" de datos binarios.

**El "Problema Unicode"**: Como las DOMStrings son cadenas codificadas en 16 bits, en la mayoría de navegadores llamar a `window.btoa` sobre una cadena Unicode resultará en una excepción `Character Out Of Range` si un carácter excede el rango de los caracteres ASCII de 8 bits. [La gente de mozilla propone dos soluciones a esto.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_codificando_y_decodificando#El_Problema_Unicode)

**ACTUALIZACION:**
Para la otra parte de la pregunta aquí esta como crear archivos. Este código es utilizando la API File de HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>API FILE: Directories and Systems</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fileDirAndSysCrear.css" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fileDirAndSysCrear.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="cajaFormulario">
            <form name="formulario">
                <p>Nombre:<br/><input type="text" name="entrada" id="entrada" required /></p>
                <p><br/><input type="button" name="boton" id="boton" value="Crear archivo" />
                <input type="button" name="boton2" id="boton2" value="Crear carpeta" /></p>
            </form>
        </section>
        <section id="cajadatos">
            No hay entradas disponibles
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

y el javascript es este:

```
function iniciar(){
    cajadatos=document.getElementById("cajadatos");
    var boton=document.getElementById("boton");
    var boton2=document.getElementById("boton2");
    boton.addEventListener("click",crearArchivo,false);
    boton2.addEventListener("click",crearCarpeta,false);
    window.webkitRequestFileSystem(TEMPORARY,5*1024*1024,creardd,errores);
}
function creardd(sistema){
    dd=sistema.root;
}
function crearArchivo(){
    var nombre=document.getElementById("entrada").value;
    if(nombre!=""){
        dd.getFile(nombre,{create:true,exclusive:false},mostrar,errores);//Crea archivo
    }
}
function crearCarpeta(){
    var carpeta=document.getElementById("entrada").value;
    if(carpeta!=""){
        dd.getDirectory(carpeta,{create:true,exclusive:false},mostrar,errores);//Crea carpeta
    }
}
function mostrar(entrada){
    document.getElementById("entrada").value="";
    cajadatos.innerHTML="Entrada creada!<br/>";
    cajadatos.innerHTML+="Nombre: "+entrada.name+"<br/>";
    cajadatos.innerHTML+="Ruta: "+entrada.fullPath+"<br/>";
    cajadatos.innerHTML+="Sistema: "+entrada.filesystem.name+"<br/>";
}
function errores(e){
    alert("Error: "+/*e.code+*/"\nname: "+e.name+"\nmessage: "+e.message);
}
window.addEventListener("load",iniciar,false);
```

El css:

```
#cajaformulario{
    float:left;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
}
#cajadatos{
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #999999;
}
.directorio{
    color:#0000FF;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: OP quiere crear un archivo con un base64.